# tf.ones(dtype=tf.float32) or tf.ones(dtype=tf.int32) behave differently

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use `dtype = tf.float32`,

```
import tensorflow as tf

z = tf.Variable(tf.ones(5, dtype=tf.float32), name='z')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:

        session.run(init)
        print("z=" , session.run(z))
        for i in range(5):
            z = z +1 
            print(session.run(z))
```

I got the result like this:

```
('z=', array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32))
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

However, when I use `dtype=tf.int32`，

```
z = tf.Variable(tf.ones(5, dtype=tf.int32), name='z')
```

I got the result:

```
('z=', array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32))
[2 2 2 2 2]
[3 3 3 3 3]
[4 4 4 4 4]
[5 5 5 5 5]
[6 6 6 6 6]
```

Can you help me why it seems not correctly when use **tf.float32**?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Which tf version are you using?

Comment: Using your code, `tf.float32` worked correctly on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04, TF 1.7).

Comment: I use (Ubuntu16.04, TF1.3)