# tf.ones returns zeros instead of ones

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why is `tf.ones` returning zeros? My version is `'2.3.0'` and I'm using an Anaconda environment.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.ones((3, 3))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

I don't understand what's going on... But if I use dtype `tf.int32` it works:

```
tf.ones((3, 3), dtype=tf.int32)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])>
```

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675178/tf-onesdtype-tf-float32-or-tf-onesdtype-tf-int32-behave-differently) had the same issue.

Comment: Could you try using numpy directly with `np.ones`, to see if the problem persists? That could at least be a workaround, if I remember correctly you can use the result of numpy functions directly in tensorflow

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in Google Colab with TF 2.3.0 - first array consists of `1.`, too.

Comment: you may have accidentally overwritten some function of `tf` in your code without noticing it. Please also try restarting python and try again (or even reinstalling package)

Comment: It works with Numpy. @desertnaut that is interesting. Is it with Python 3.7.7?

Comment: Solved by downgrading to TF 2.1

Comment: with Python 3.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, your Python installation doesn't support tensorflow 2.3.0. For instance, Anaconda works properly only with TF 2.1.0

Comment: I solved it by downgrading to Tensorflow 2.1, now `tf.ones` works as expected.