# In tensorflow-gpu, tensor in tf.ones is filled with zeros. Is this a bug?

Tags: tensorflow

My environment

python 3.7.9 (anaconda venv)
tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0
keras 2.3.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GZUm.png)

Comment: Have you installed TF from the Anaconda channel? `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu==2.1` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363859/tf-ones-returns-zeros-instead-of-ones.

Comment: Hi! This issue is not replicating in Latest stable version TF 2.6 . Thanks!